# SQL Combine 2 rows into 2 columns

Tags: sql, merge

I have a table that contains entries like this:

[image]

I would like to transfor it to something like this:

[image]

Can't find how to do so with a group by only. Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Entity,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type=Auto THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS ValueAuto,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type=Manual THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS ValueMaual
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Entity
```

Comment: For completeness we will need to include region the group by and in the select list.

Comment: Thank you. How would you do if the 'Value' was actually string?

Answer (score 0):

above query returns the good values if we have only two types, If I don't know how many groups are there in the table, dynamically how can do with the case statement.

Use UN-PIVOT is the best options to solve the above requirements.